# Monotonicity of a positive function that vanishes at a point

Tags: real-analysis, limits, derivatives

Suppose we have a positive function $f(x): \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$, $f \geq 0$, that vanishes at a point $x_0$, i.e., $f(x_0) = 0$. Suppose that $f$ is continuously differentiable on $\mathbb{R} \setminus \{x_0\}$.

From these assumptions, are we able to conclude that there exists a neighborhood $(x_0 - \delta, x_0 + \delta)$ such that $f$ is increasing on $[x_0, x_0+\delta)$ and decreasing on $(x_0 - \delta, x_0]$ ?

If I am correct, this would be correct if $f$ were to be differentiable on all $\mathbb{R}$, but I do not know if the non-differentiability of $f$ at $x_0$ makes the statement wrong. I think also $f$ being positive does not allow for counterexamples such as in https://mathoverflow.net/questions/167323/everywhere-differentiable-function-that-is-nowhere-monotonic.

Thank you

Comment: Function can be constant

Comment: This is wrong, even for differentiable functions. Counterexamples look like $f(x) = x^2 \sin(1/x)^2$ for $x \ne 0$, $f(0) = 0$.

Comment: Does this change if we suppose that $f(x) > 0$ for all $x \neq x_0$ ? This would (I think) not allow for the counterexamples that you have stated.

Comment: @ShurikG.: $f(x) = x^2(\sin(1/x)^2 + 1/2)$ is strictly positive for $x > 0$, and not monotone in any neighborhood of the origin.